# Why use ViewContainerRef over *ngif?

Tags: angular, dom, angular-components, angular-ng-if, dom-manipulation

I could just do

```
<my-awesome-component *ngIf="ConditionToIncludeComponent"></my-awesome-component>
```

But every document on inserting component in dom dynamically is based on ViewContainerRef. I like what it does. But what makes it so special over *ngif?

Just point out pros and cons of both. Please.
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### TLDR;

If you don't know what component will be used in a component template when putting together this template use `viewContainerRef`. If you do know the component beforehand but it can sometimes be hidden, use `ngIf`.

#### Explanation

`ViewContainerRef` is used to specify the insertion point of the **dynamic** component.  When using `ngIf` you need to specify the component in `html` **in advance**. So if you have a spot where you will insert one of three components you will need to do the following:

```
<my-awesome-component1 *ngIf="ConditionToIncludeComponent1"></my-awesome-component1>
<my-awesome-component2 *ngIf="ConditionToIncludeComponent2"></my-awesome-component2>
<my-awesome-component3 *ngIf="ConditionToIncludeComponent3"></my-awesome-component3>
```

Whereas with `viewContainerRef` you need only one spot (usually specified using `ng-container). Using [ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) it can be done like this:

```
template: `<ng-container ngComponentOutlet="componentToInsert"></ng-container>`

class MyComponent {

   const myAwesomeComponent1 = cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyAwesomeComponent1);
   const myAwesomeComponent2 = cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyAwesomeComponent1);
   const myAwesomeComponent3 = cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyAwesomeComponent1);
       
    if (ConditionToIncludeComponent1) {
        componentToInsert = myAwesomeComponent1;
    else if (ConditionToIncludeComponent2) {
        componentToInsert = myAwesomeComponent2;
    else if (ConditionToIncludeComponent3) {
        componentToInsert = myAwesomeComponent3;
```

Or component manually using `createComponent` method:

```
template: `<ng-container #spot></ng-container>`

class MyComponent {
   @ViewChild('spot', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc;

   const myAwesomeComponent1 = cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyAwesomeComponent1);
   const myAwesomeComponent2 = cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyAwesomeComponent1);
   const myAwesomeComponent3 = cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyAwesomeComponent1);
       
    if (ConditionToIncludeComponent1) {
        vc.createComponent(myAwesomeComponent1);
    else if (ConditionToIncludeComponent2) {
        vc.createComponent(myAwesomeComponent2);
    else if (ConditionToIncludeComponent3) {
        vc.createComponent(myAwesomeComponent3);
```

Besides inconvenience and a bloated html template the bigger problem with the `ngIf` approach is performance impact since three `ngIf` directives will have to perform some logic on each change detection cycle.

For more information read:

- [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)

Comment: Does that mean if I use ngIf, the component is already there but hidden? I will check your article for sure. Can you post another article on the topic of my question. I think lots of people on internet search for it. Thanks!

Comment: @Prabesh, no, `ngIf` will not create a component if it evaluates to `false`. But the instances of `ngIf` directives will be created. And Angular will be spending some time on each instance of `ngIf` during change detection. If you don't know what component will be used when putting together a component template. If you do know the component but it can sometimes be hidden, use `ngIf`. I'll think about the article suggestion, thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure I will be using ViewContainerRef from now on. thanks for putting time on my question. Currently, I want to create a comment section for pictures where top 5 comments will load after Comment button is clicked. and A comment box at last. Its obvious that i have to use ngFor for comments to load . So, how do you suggest should i combine ngFor and ViewContainerRef to make it work. And this means i need antoher <ng-container> for that comment box, right?

Comment: @Prabesh, can you please create another question an post a link here?

Comment: @MaxWizardK  Say, if i am showing a html table with multiple rows (generated using *ngFor), and show a tooltip component on hover of each row.So i should use *ngIf like `<tr *ngFor="let subitemObj of myArray"><app-tooltip-comp *ngIf='subitemObj.showTooltip'></app-tooltip-comp></tr>` , or i should use `viewcontainerRef` to insert this component dynamically on each hover on the `tr` tag.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, I don't think there's a need here for dynamic components. This is what viewcontainerref for.

Comment: @MaxWizardK thanks, then ngIF is better option as i have my component and its not a dynamic one.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, yes, you know what component you want in advance. Read [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) to understand why we need dynamic components