# When to use Angular Dynamic Component Loader?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been exploring Angular Dynamic component loader and still not able to get that, when exactly do I need to use this.

**Current Scenario:**
I am getting data of widgets as array of objects. On the basis of each array element I am trying to create a component.

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets">
  <span *ngIf="widget.name=='circle'">
    <circle-widget [model]="widget"></circle-widget>
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="widget.name=='numeric'">
    <numeric-widget [model]="widget"></numeric-widget>
  </span>
</div>
```

Same thing I can achieve using dynamic component loader.

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets">
  <dynamic-comp-loader [model]="widget"></dynamic-comp-loader> 
</div>
```

**DynamicCompLoader.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-comp-loader',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-comp-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-comp-loader.component.scss'],
})

ngOnInit(){
  const componentClass = this.getComponentClass(this.model.compName);
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentClass.component);
  const viewContainerRef = this.appDynamicCompLoader.viewContainerRef;
  viewContainerRef.clear();
  if (this.componentRef) {
    this.componentRef.destroy();
  }
  this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

Both the cases are working fine and rendering respective components, but I need to understand:-

- When should we use dynamic component loader?
- Is there any performance issue in using either of them?
- Which is the best way to render components on the basis of Iterating elements from array?

Comment: Can anybody please have a look on this?

Comment: You can use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-component-launcher library and save you having to deal with the steps of dynamically loading components in Angular.

Comment: this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670125/why-use-viewcontainerref-over-ngif